# change the active menu color on mouse over and click event using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>menu</title>
        <style>
            .highlight, .highlight_stay {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('li a').hover(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                }, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                });
                $('li a').click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">list1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">list2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">sublist1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">sublist2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">sublist3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">sublist4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">list3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">list4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Its changing all the lists into red color. But, I want the following requirement.

The first time I click, `list1`, it changes into red color. If I click `list2` at 2nd time, `list1` will change to its original color and `list2` will be in red color. Like wise it want to work. At the same time on mouse over also want to activate the list as red color.

Any one can help? Please!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the click handler to first remove the `highlight_stay` class from any element that currently has it.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $('.highlight_stay').removeClass('highlight_stay');
    $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gFzL2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass('highlight_stay');
    $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/VpmbL/1159/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for the hover, it's far more efficient than jQuery.  You can use .each to remove all the highlights before highlighting the one you want.  I just made a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Ezb4v/

```
$(function () {
    $('li a').click(function () {
        $('li a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        });
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: Speaking of efficient, you don't need that `.each()`. Just say `$('li a').removeClass(...)`.